# Move committed and pushed changes to a different branch

Tags: git

I have made changes to my code (the "alpha" branch) which I have committed over the course of a few weeks (i.e. several commits) and pushed up to the repository, for all to see.

Now I realise that what I should have done was created a new "beta" branch and made my changes there, leaving the "alpha" branch alone.

Is there a way of creating a "beta" branch, and moving my commits to it, and removing them from the "alpha" branch, i.e. set that back to the last valid change (7 commits ago).

Any searches I have for doing this involves creating a new branch with my changes, then doing a git reset... e.g.

https://careerkarma.com/blog/git-move-commit-to-another-branch/

suggests something like

```
git branch beta    // Supposedly takes my latest changes and puts it into a new branch, "beta"
git reset --hard [[commitId]]  // Should set the "alpha" branch back to [commitId]
git checkout beta   // Allows me to continue my work on "beta".
```

The main part being the middle line , `git reset --hard` . However while this sets my codebase back to *[commitId]*, it has no effect on the repository, so whoever else wants to work with the "alpha" code still has my changes. If they also do a `git reset --hard` as I did, then they won't be able to make their own code changes because when they try to commit they will get an error saying they are behind the current commit.

What is the right thing to do here?

Even if there is a way of setting my codebase back to *[commitId]*, but in such a way that it's considered a change, so when I commit & push again, it will push up all the reverted changes.

Comment: The "right" thing is _do not rewrite history that has already been shared_. It's fine to make a new `beta` branch but don't do a `reset`. If you want to remove the _effect_ of the commits from `alpha` use `revert`, not `reset`.

Comment: You just need to push your branches to the remote repo. So, push out `beta` and force push out `alpha`. **However**, as @matt mentioned in a comment, you can't just blindly force push out `alpha` without potentially messing up people that have already started new branches off of `alpha`. So, make sure your team is aware and OK with you resetting `alpha` before your roll it back, otherwise, revert instead.